# Make use of implicit conversion operator inside expression tree

Tags: c#, expression-trees, implicit-conversion

Suppose I have the following type with an implicit convertion operator:

```cs
public readonly struct WrappedInt
{
    public WrappedInt(int value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }

    public int Value { get; }

    public static implicit operator int (WrappedInt wrapper) => wrapper.Value;
}
```

Then here is an application:

```cs
var wrapper = new WrappedInt(42);
int x1 = Unwrap(wrapper);
int x2 = UnwrapUsingExpression(wrapper);

private static int Unwrap(WrappedInt wrapper)
{
    int result = wrapper;
    return result;
}

private static int UnwrapUsingExpression(WrappedInt wrapper)
{
    var wrapperParameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(typeof(WrappedInt), "wrapper");
    var resultVariableExpression = Expression.Variable(typeof(int), "result");

    Expression right = wrapperParameterExpression;     // THIS is important
    var assignExpression = Expression.Assign(resultVariableExpression, right);
    var blockExpression = Expression.Block(
        new ParameterExpression[] { resultVariableExpression },
        new Expression[] { resultVariableExpression, assignExpression, resultVariableExpression }
    );

    var unwrapFunc = Expression.Lambda<Func<WrappedInt, int>>(blockExpression, wrapperParameterExpression).Compile();
    return unwrapFunc(wrapper);
}
```

Please note that in the `Unwrap` function I do `int result = wrapper;` which uses my implicit convertion operator - fine.

Now I want to do the same but in the expression tree - `UnwrapWithExpression` routine. Here I'm assigning my 'result' variable directly to 'wrapper' parameter using

`Expression right = wrapperParameterExpression;`

But this does not work - I get a runtime exception:

> System.ArgumentException: 'Expression of type 'WrappedInt' cannot be used for assignment to type 'System.Int32'.

I know how to work around it, basically either access the `Value` property:

`Expression right = Expression.Property(wrapperParameterExpression, nameof(WrappedInt.Value));`

Or converting it:

`Expression right = Expression.Convert(wrapperParameterExpression, typeof(int));`

But why I cannot simply use the original direct assignment and make my implicit operator do the work?

Comment: Expressions are a lot more restrictive than normal C#, particularly around implicit type conversions. These are just the rules you need to play within.

Comment: In the normal way the compiler does its magic for the implicit conversion. With expressions you have to be more explicit.

Comment: Hmm I see, so I guess I'll just stick with one of my workarounds then. Not very good with expressions yet so are such restrictions specified/listed somewhere? Or one would come across them by trial and error?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6187664/implicit-cast-not-happening-in-expression-tree

Comment: Expressions are pretty much trial-and-error (though the [Expression docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.expression?view=netframework-4.8) do help), and looking at what the compiler will generate if you create an expression using a lambda (DebugView helps here). I wouldn't say using `Expression.Convert` is a workaround - you are *actually* doing a conversion. It's just that the C# compiler silently inserts it for you.

Comment: @canton7, Makes sence, thanks. You might want to post that as answer so the question can be closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expressions are more restrictive than C# in many ways, particularly around implicit type conversions. You will find many cases where the C# compiler will insert a type conversion for you, but where you need to add an explicit `Expression.Convert`.

If you want to call the implicit conversion method, you will need to add an `Expression.Convert`. This is how expressions work, for better or for worse. Doing so is not a workaround.

If you write the expression:

```
Expression<Func<WrappedInt, int>> convert = x => x;
```

and then look at `convert.DebugView` in a debugger, you see this:

```
.Lambda #Lambda1<System.Func`2[WrappedInt,System.Int32]>(WrappedInt $x) {
    (System.Int32)$x
}
```

That `(System.Int32)$x` is a `Convert` node (which you can verify by looking at `convert.Body` in the debugger). The compiler's decided that the best equivalent to that C# in the land of Expressions is `Expression.Convert`, so that is what you should do, too.